# Pass array of object from one to another component in nested components in angular?

Tags: angular

I need to pass the array of object from vehicle-operations component to edit-vehicle-operations component for editing/updating purpose. I tried with @input @ViewChild like these, nothing helped. I have given my project structure in the below stackblitz link. If it is not helping you please give me some successions.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r8gzfq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvehicle-management%2Fvehicle-operations%2Fvehicle-operations.component.ts)

Comment: Seems like the components are unrelated. Quickest way would be to setup a singleton service and share the array through it.

Answer (score 1):

As Mentioned by @MichaelD You can use a service to achieve this

Create a service

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {

  vehiclesSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject([])
  vehicles$ = this.vehiclesSubject$.asObservable()
  updateVehicles(vehicles) {
    console.log(vehicles)
    this.vehiclesSubject$.next(vehicles)
  }
  constructor() { }

}
```

On the component you need to send the update you can call the next value on the Subject

**VehicleOperationsComponent**

```typescript
this.vehicleService.updateVehicles(this.vehicles);
```

**EditVehicleOperationsComponent**

```typescript
vehicle$ = this.vehicleService.vehicles$
```

You can now subscribe to this value **EditVehicleOperationsComponent**
Using async pipe this can be done with

```html
<pre>{{ vehicle$ | async | json }}</pre>
```

[See this fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m8ttke)